# How to suppress Output Message from Python yfinance package?

Tags: python, yfinance

I am trying to get stock ratings using the yfinance python package with the following line:

```
recommendations = yf.Ticker("ANSCU").upgrades_downgrades
```

This works well until I run into some tickers that has no ratings (such as ANSCU). In such case I get a regular message that is intended to be an error message:

```
404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/ANSCU?modules=upgradeDowngradeHistory&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&form
```

This is ok and I can move on to next ticker. However, there is no option to suppress this ulgy looking 404 message. I tried redirecting system output:

```
print("A")
text_trap = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = text_trap
print("B")
recommendations = yf.Ticker("ANSCU").upgrades_downgrades
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print("C")
```

It does work on my own function's output but it does not work from within yfinance package codings as follows:

```
A
404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/ANSCU?modules=upgradeDowngradeHistory&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&formatted=false&symbol=ANSCU&crumb=tpwxFnmHnDw
C
```

Wonder if there is anyway to suppress the "404..." message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is a log message, not a simple print statement.

Here is one way to disable the log messages:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('yfinance')
logger.disabled = True
logger.propagate = False
```